# Docker - require specific docker service version

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Currently I have a bug, maybe in my code, maybe in docker base images, maybe even in docker itself, but I know for sure, that my app works great on `docker-ce 17.09` and hang up after some time on `docker-ce 17.12`
Is there any way to specify docker version in `Dockerfile` or in `docker-compose.yml` so app will throw error while trying to build it on not supported docker version.
I understand this is not a good idea, and I need to find out this bug, but for temporary workaround this error message is enough for me.

Comment: after hangup issue  docker ps -a  then issue   docker logs container-id-hung-one   ... update your question with output ... sometimes this log is helpful

Comment: Yeah, I already seen logs and there is no error, just logs stopped at some time, but container is running

Comment: Take a look at docker version manager https://howtowhale.github.io/dvm/ so you can switch between versions and try commands

Comment: @slashpai yeah thanks, but I'm not have trouble installing older version of docker (it's pretty easy on ubuntu), but my trouble is prohibit using newer version for current app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think there is no docker direct approach to it. But you can pass the docker version with `ARG` to your Dockerfile and then add `RUN` command that checks if it is the required version. To cancel the build process you have to `exit` with other number than 0.

build your image with this line

```
docker_version=`docker version --format "{{.Server.Version}}"` \
&& docker build -t my_image --build-arg DOCKER_VERSION=$docker_version .
```

then in your **Dockerfile** check if it is required docker version

```
FROM debian

ARG DOCKER_VERSION

RUN [[ $DOCKER_VERSION == "17.12.0-ce" ]] && echo "YES" ||  exit 1
```

Comment: Yeah, seem like this would work, but looks a lot of troubles :) Thanks anyway